How to deserialize json that is either string or an object in Kotlin?
I have json that can either be a string or an object. How do I deserialize this in Kotlin?
val json = """
    {
        "hello": {
            "foo": "string"
        }
    }
"""

val json2 = """
    {
        "hello": {
            "foo": {
                "bar": "string"
            }
        }
    }
""".trimIndent()

val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
val hello = mapper.readValue(json, MyJson::class.java)
val hello2 = mapper.readValue(json2, MyJson::class.java)

I can trivially deserialize either of these json objects, but i'm not too sure how to deserialize a json object that could be one of either of these. I.e. the foo field could either be a string, or an object, and I'm not sure how to deserialize that.

Combine them how?  What are you expecting?  They have the same outer key.

Does this answer your question? Jackson Deserializer for one custom field?
